# Too many LET clauses cause slow query, but cannot use extension method in place

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have entities which have regular readings taken with many (18) values. These values may or may not have alarms set and therefore have a 'status'.

I need to make some calculations during linq to entities queries. I need to compare the alarm status of 18 different values and get the worst status of the lot. I CANNOT save the status with the readings and recalculate when the entity alarms change. I'm having problems implementing this in an efficient way.

This doesn't work: I can't use extension methods `... GetOverallStatus(..) cannot be translated into a store expression...`

```
from reading in db.Readings
let OverallStatus = reading.GetOverallStatus()
select new StatusModel() { Reading = reading, Status = (StatusValue)overallStatus }).ToList();
```

This does work but (understandably) takes an age to compile when called:

```
from reading in db.Readings
let entity = reading.entity
let Value1Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value1 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm1AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value1 >= entity.Alarm1Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value1 >= entity.Alarm1Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value2Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value2 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm2AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value2 >= entity.Alarm2Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value2 >= entity.Alarm2Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value3Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value3 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm3AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value3 >= entity.Alarm3Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value3 >= entity.Alarm3Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value4Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value4 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm4AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value4 >= entity.Alarm4Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value4 >= entity.Alarm4Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value5Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value5 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm5AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value5 >= entity.Alarm5Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value5 >= entity.Alarm5Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value6Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value6 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm6AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value6 >= entity.Alarm6Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value6 >= entity.Alarm6Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value7Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value7 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm7AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value7 >= entity.Alarm7Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value7 >= entity.Alarm7Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value8Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value8 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm8AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value8 >= entity.Alarm8Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value8 >= entity.Alarm8Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value9Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value9 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm9AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value9 >= entity.Alarm9Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value9 >= entity.Alarm9Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value10Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value10 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm10AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value10 >= entity.Alarm10Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value10 >= entity.Alarm10Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value11Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value11 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm11AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value11 >= entity.Alarm11Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value11 >= entity.Alarm11Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value12Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value12 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm12AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value12 >= entity.Alarm12Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value12 >= entity.Alarm12Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value13Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value13 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm13AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value13 >= entity.Alarm13Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value13 >= entity.Alarm13Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value14Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value14 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm14AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value14 >= entity.Alarm14Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value14 >= entity.Alarm14Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value15Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value15 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm15AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value15 >= entity.Alarm15Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value15 >= entity.Alarm15Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value16Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value16 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm16AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value16 >= entity.Alarm16Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value16 >= entity.Alarm16Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value17Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value17 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm17AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value17 >= entity.Alarm17Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value17 >= entity.Alarm17Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let Value18Status = !runSpeedOK || reading.Value18 == null ? (noReadings : (!(entity.Alarm18AlarmsOn ?? false) ? (notConfig : (reading.Value18 >= entity.Alarm18Critical ? (critical : (reading.Value18 >= entity.Alarm18Warning ? (warning : (ok)))
let OverallStatus = (new int[18] { Value1Status, Value2Status, Value3Status, Value4Status, Value5Status, Value6Status, Value7Status, Value8Status, Value9Status, Value10Status, Value11Status, Value12Status, Value13Status, Value14Status, Value15Status, Value16Status, Value17Status, Value18Status }).Max()
select new StatusModel() { Reading = reading, Status = (StatusValue)overallStatus }).ToList();
```

This is, of course, another options which is both the best and cleanest and I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier. Clearly blinkered by frustration:

```
foreach (var reading in db.Readings.ToList())
{
    result.Add(new ReportVibReadingStatusModel() { Reading = reading, Status = reading.GetOverallStatusValue() });
}
```

Comment: Yes. I agree. How to make it better?

Comment: I'm assuming that `StatusValue` is an enum. Do you currently have them mapped to int values (or could you, in order of degree)?

Comment: Make `Value` an entity/table of its own and put them together in a 1-n relationship. This is a poorly normalized design.

Comment: Yes that is entirely possible, I have a global constants class that I can access for the values. Is the casting responsible for a lot of the inefficiency then?

Comment: @GertArnold the entire data storage structure is atrociously normalized, it is a constant thorn in my side

Comment: Why not return all readings in order of say, alarm number, then iterate through the readings in a foreach loop and ascertain which is the worst status, then report? or once you have all readings retruend from your L2E code call db.Readings.GetOverallStatus() (this is then a Linq statement not converted to SQL as L2E will do ? (agreed that I don't know what is in GetOverallStatus())

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that now we can see the pile of poo you are burried in, give some psuedo code / logic and you may get more help.

Comment: Get the basic data first and then use the extension method on the data in memory.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, exactly! I have just put that in my question as the clearly more efficient option. I can't believe I didn't think of it ealier. I wish you'd put this as the answer so I could accept it!

Answer (score 0):

I must confess i'm not overly familiar with entity framework, but i know it supports stored procedures. I would write a stored procedure to return the values that can be determined purely on the SQL side. Meaning, all those ValueStatuses.

I probably would have put this as a question in the comments, but I can't yet :)

Comment: I've thought about StoredProcedures, but unfortunately that also comes under the 'don't touch nor change the database but fix it anyhow' category

Comment: I feel your pain. Sorry i wasn't able to help, but i'm glad you came up with something that works for you!